# Testing React-redux-es6-webpack applications with wallaby.js

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, redux, visual-studio-code

How should I configure and write test cases for React-redux-es6-webpack application with wallaby.js. Please specify how to run the test cases also. I use visual studio code as editor

I have gone through https://github.com/wallabyjs/wallaby-webpack-es6-react and http://dm.gl/2015/03/11/wallaby-react/
But it throws error. I think I missed something in configuration. Please help me out

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please share your config and the error you're getting in our repo at https://github.com/wallabyjs/public/issues

Comment: I have shared my issue in https://github.com/wallabyjs/public/issues/370